# php snmpget physical address returns a value with stripped leading 0's

Tags: php, macos, snmp

Does anyone have any experience with mac address values via SNMP get in php where it seems to take off the leading 0's?

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to make sure they don't get stripped when I return a value.

For example

```
IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.1 = STRING: 0:80:ea:8c:a:e1
Should give me 
00:80:ea:8c:0a:e1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP SNMP client is formatting the returned MIB object value incorrectly.
If you have the source code it is probably a trivial fix.

Answer (score 0):

use -O OUTOPTS
Toggle various defaults controlling output display:
0:  print leading 0 for single-digit hex characters

snmpget -v2c -c public  IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.1 -O 0

Comment: This answer would be a lot more readable if you put the code in code blocks. You can use backtics(\`) around code and it will get the `code format`. It is also useful for showing expected output.